# okhttp3 moshi - JsonAdapter runtime issue

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, moshi

I'm trying to run a sample code that uses okhttp3 to make Rest api calls.

**MoshiJsonConvertor.kt:**

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import java.io.IOException

class MoshiJsonConvertor {
    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    private val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    private val gistJsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Gist::class.java)

    fun run() {
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.github.com/gists/c2a7c39532239ff261be")
                .build()
        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
            if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

            val gist = gistJsonAdapter.fromJson(response.body!!.source())

            for ((key, value) in gist!!.files!!) {
                println(key)
                println(value.content)
            }
        }
    }

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Gist(var files: Map<String, GistFile>?)

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class GistFile(var content: String?)
}

fun main() {
    MoshiJsonConvertor().run()
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.1'
}
```

When I run the code I get following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter

```
class for class MoshiJsonConvertor$Gist
    at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:542)
    at com.squareup.moshi.StandardJsonAdapters$1.create(StandardJsonAdapters.java:60)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:138)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:98)
    at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:72)
    at MoshiJsonConvertor.<init>(MoshiJsonConvertor.kt:10)
    at MoshiJsonConvertorKt.main(MoshiJsonConvertor.kt:36)
    at MoshiJsonConvertorKt.main(MoshiJsonConvertor.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MoshiJsonConvertor_GistJsonAdapter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.generatedAdapter(Util.java:516)
    ... 7 more
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.9.1'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.1'
}
```